# Why is Illustrator adding a fill here?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

What I am doing is, I open up a file I saved as an Illustrator template, which I have used several times to create icons. What's happening is, I created a rounded rectangle and set it for a 2px stroke, but no fill, yet Illustrator is filling it with this off brown color. Why is that?[image]

Here's a shot with the Layers panel:
[image: Layers panel]

Comment: *Something* has a fill applied.. maybe the group or layer that it is in?

Comment: Open the Appearance panel and show what it says with this selection.

Comment: it shows the black stroke and no fill, that's what it's showing, so what's going on with the fill?

Comment: the fill does not have to come from the object it can come from the layer too. Show your layer panel expanded so we see the objects too.

Comment: Ok, I added a screenshot with the Layers panel here above.

Answer (score 1):

As previously commented the layer "Layer 1" has an appearance override. You can see this because the circle next to the name is filled. Click on the filled circle and clear appearance in the appearances panel and you are clear of the effect.

Note, slecting a item in the layers panel does not select the object unless you click on the circle.

Comment: You guys are great! that solved the problem.

Comment: @DanielBaker: and yet you haven't [accepted any answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for all of your questions!